# CASE in JOIN not working PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, join, case

I got the following tables:

Teams

[image: Teams]

Matches

[image: Matches]

I want to get an output like:

```
matches.semana | teams.nom_equipo | teams.nom_equipo | Winner
       1              AMERICA         CRUZ AZUL        AMERICA
       1              SANTOS           MORELIA         MORELIA
       1               LEON            CHIVAS            LEON
```

The columns teams.nom_equipo reference to matches.num_eqpo_lo & to matches.num_eqpo_v and at the same time they reference to the column teams.nom_equipo to get the name of each team based on their id

**Edit: I have used the following:**

```
SELECT m.semana, t_loc.nom_equipo AS LOCAL, t_vis.nom_equipo AS VISITANTE,
       CASE WHEN m.goles_loc > m.goles_vis THEN 'home'
            WHEN m.goles_vis > m.goles_loc THEN 'visitor'
            ELSE 'tie'
       END AS Vencedor 
FROM matches AS m
JOIN teams AS t_loc ON (m.num_eqpo_loc = t_loc.num_eqpo)
JOIN teams AS t_vis ON (m.num_eqpo_vis = t_vis.num_eqpo)
ORDER BY m.semana;
```

**But as you can see from the table Matches in row #5 from the goles_loc column (home team) & goles_vis (visitor) column, they have 2 vs 2 (number of goals - home vs visitor) being a tie but and when I run the code I get something that is not a tie**:

Matches' score

[image: Matches]

Resultset from Select:

[image: Result]

**I also noticed that since the row #5 the names of both teams in the matches are not correct (both visitor & home team).
So, the Select brings correct data but in other order different than the original order (referring to the order from the table matches)**

The order from the second week must be:

```
        matches.semana | teams.nom_equipo | teams.nom_equipo |   Winner
  5            2              CRUZ AZUL         TOLUCA            TIE
  6            2              MORELIA           LEON              LEON
  7            2               CHIVAS           SANTOS            TIE
```

Row 8 from the Resultset must be Row # 5 and so on.

Any help would be really thanked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing a `SELECT` which includes `null` for a column, that's the value it will always be, so `winner` in your case will never be populated.

Something like this is probably more along the lines of what you want:

```
SELECT m.semana, t_loc.nom_equipo AS loc_equipo, t_vis.nom_equipo AS vis_equipo,
       CASE WHEN m.goles_loc - m.goles_vis > 0 THEN t_loc.nom_equipo
            WHEN m.goles_vis - m.goles_loc > 0 THEN t_vis.nom_equipo
            ELSE NULL
       END AS winner 
FROM matches AS m
JOIN teams AS t_loc ON (m.nom_eqpo_loc = t.num_eqpo)
JOIN teams AS t_vis ON (m.nom_eqpo_vis = t.num_eqpo)
ORDER BY m.semana;
```

Untested, but this should provide the general approach. Basically, you `JOIN` to the `teams` table twice, but using different conditions, and then you need to calculate the scores. I'm using `NULL` to indicate a tie, here.

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

It's the same table -- `teams` -- but the `JOIN`s produce different results, because the query uses different `JOIN` *conditions* in each `JOIN`.

The first `JOIN`, for `t_loc`, compares `m.nom_eqpo_loc` to `t.num_eqpo`. This means it gets the `teams` rows for the **home** team.

The second `JOIN`, for `t_vis`, compares `m.nom_eqpo_vis` to `t.num_eqpo`. This means it gets the `teams` rows for the **visting** team.

Therefore, in the `CASE` statement, `t_loc` refers to the **home** team, while `t_vis` refers to the **visting** one, enabling both to be used in the `CASE` statement, enabling the correct name to be found for `winning`.

**Edit in response to follow-up comment from OP:**

My original query was sorting by `m.semana`, which means other columns can appear in any order (essentially whichever *Postgres* feels is most efficient).

If you want the resulting table to be sorted exactly the same way as the `matches` table, then use the same `ORDER BY` *tuple* in its `ORDER BY`.

So, the `ORDER BY` clause would then become:

`ORDER BY m.semana, m.nom_eqpo_loc, m.nom_eqpo_vis`

Basically, the `matches` table `PRIMARY KEY` tuple.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Added to answer. Also, you'll want to switch `matches.semana` to `m.semana` -- that's what's leading to your new error.

Comment: I wonder why some of the names of the teams do not match and because of that none of the subsequent scores do :/

Comment: Did the `ORDER BY` changes I added to the answer show the results you were expecting?

Comment: Yeah. The Resultset from Select screenshot is the one being executed with the  `ORDER BY ` instruction and the order is the opposite. The first record is the last shown and so on :/

Comment: Not sure I quite understand... they still aren't in the order you are expecting? What order are they in with my changes above vs. what you are expecting?

Comment: Starting with row #5. It should have CRUZ AZUL         TOLUCA            TIE and it shows different. The same for the following rows. Take a look to the last screenshot & las code block I added to my post

Comment: According to the last code block you added, you're sorting only on `m.semana`. My last edit suggested changing it to `ORDER BY m.semana, m.nom_eqpo_loc, m.nom_eqpo_vis`. What happens when you do that?

Comment: Done. I did not realize the Edit you just made. Now it works. Thanks for your answer & help!